# Run GitHub Status Check Before Merge But Not On Every Commit

Tags: git, jenkins, github, continuous-integration, circleci

Is it possible to prevent merges of branches on GitHub if CI fails, but not to run CI on every commit?

Here's a bit more context. We have a protected `master` branch on GitHub and a number of short-lived feature branches. You can only merge your branch via a pull request and if it's been approved and the CI passes. The CI status is communicated via the GitHub's status checks. And the CI is run on every commit to that branch.

The problem is it takes 30 minutes to run a CI job. Also we have to pay for every minute it runs. Now, of course, there could be ways to make it run faster.

But is there a way not to run the CI on every commit to a feature branch, but just between the moment the 'Merge' button is pressed and the actual merge occurs?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to do this.

GitHub doesn't even let you access the merge button until the branch is green with the way you have it configured.  Furthermore, the way CI tools work with GitHub is by getting notification of pushes to a pull request.  Therefore, the only time your CI system gets notified is when a PR is opened or when new data gets pushed to it.

It may be possible to configure your CI system not to run automatically and to store the data sent to it and then run when a button in their UI is pressed.  If it came back green, then 30 minutes later you could press the merge button.  That would be the closest thing to what you want to do, but that depends on your particular CI provider, so you'd have to inquire about it with them.